# How can I access a class variable in my HTML when using Typescript?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code in my controller and HTML:

```
class AccessWebApiController {

    method;
    response;
    statusCode;
    tab = {
        selected: null
    };

    static $inject = [
        '$http',
        '$scope',
        '$sce'
    ];
    constructor(
        public $http: ng.IHttpService,
        public $scope,
        public $sce: ng.ISCEService
        ) {
        $scope = this;
        this.tab.selected = 100;
    }

} 

<main ng-controller="accessWebApiController"
      id="accessContentPage">   
    xxxx {{ tab }} xxxx 
</main>
```

Everything seems to be getting accessed correctly but the page displays and it does not show anything in bettween the xxxx and xxxx

Is there something simple I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's a problem with setting $scope = this. You can set this.scope = $scope or put this on the $scope ($scope.vm = this). Using the second option, you could change your view to {{vm.tab}}.

Answer (score 0):

$scope = this is definitely not right (and the latest typescript compiler flags it as a problem).  However, I thought some might benefit from a more complete example of this, using the controller as syntax and registering a module and the controller.  I have a plunkr for it, and I put the typescript in there but it doesn't actually do anything, so I will also put the typescript here.

Plunkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/uFuB04SUjWXYPwOSCAIW?p=preview

Code:

```
class Tab {
    public selected: number;
}

class AccessWebApiController {

    public method: any;
    public response: any;
    public statusCode: any;
    public tab: Tab;

    static $inject = [
        '$http',
        '$sce'
    ];
    constructor(
        public $http: ng.IHttpService,
        public $sce: ng.ISCEService
        ) {
        this.tab = {
            selected: null
        };
        this.tab.selected = 100;
    }

} 

var app = angular.module("WebApiModule",[]);

app.controller("accessWebApiController", ($http: ng.IHttpService, $sce: ng.ISCEService) => new AccessWebApiController($http,$sce));
```